# How to suppress GCC warnings from library headers?

Tags: gcc, warnings, suppress-warnings, gcc-warning

I have a project that uses log4cxx, boost, etc. libraries whose headers generate lots of (repetitive) warnings. Is there a way to suppress warnings from library includes (i.e. #include <some-header.h>) or includes from certain paths? I'd like to use -Wall and/or -Wextra as usual on project code without relevant info being obscured. I currently use grep on make output but I'd like something better.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You may try to include library headers using `-isystem` instead of `-I`. This will make them "system headers" and GCC won't report warnings for them.

Comment: If you're trying to do this in XCode then stick -isystem path into your "other C++ flags" in the "custom compiler flags" in your target build settings.

Comment: One potential downside is that on some platforms, g++ will automatically wrap any system headers in `extern "C"`, leading to odd errors about C linkage if you `#include` a C++ header in an `-isystem` path.

Comment: +1 helped me to solve problems with annoying boost warnings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704753/warnings-from-boost

Comment: Why does this have so many more votes than the OP's own answer that said exactly the same thing 1.5 hours earlier?

Comment: For Xcode: What if there was no folder path in "Other C++ flags" in my target build settings? Could someone elaborate on this solutions?

Comment: How to do this in eclipse ?

Comment: You should be really careful with this, and I consider this as a bad practice. This `-isystem` is meant for system libraries that are de fact standard compliant, it is not meant for silencing warnings in some third party library. Those warnings should just be fixed.

Comment: @Raffi And how do you fix warnings in a third party library that chose to suppress those warnings?

Comment: @rozina many ways: you include them with 2 guards that suppress and enable the warnings, you post pull requests upstream.

Comment: Thanks to Tavian Barnes, that was exactly the issue I had and I could not understand. g++ was failing with qt-related projects, shouting at me how stdlib.h can not be found even though it was there at /usr/include/ (but a symlink to where my glibc resides).

Answer (score 150):

For those using CMake, you can modify your `include_directories` directives to include the symbol `SYSTEM` which suppresses warnings against such headers.

```
include_directories(SYSTEM "${LIB_DIR}/Include")
                    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: What if the library provides a `${LIBFOO_USE_FILE}` variable that is to be used with CMake's [include()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html) command?

Comment: This seems to be almost the solution to my problem. I have 1.) a binary target, which depends on 2.) a header only target written by myself, which depends on 3.) some external libraries. I have no idea how to only get warnings for 1&2. You have any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I tried this with a project that uses `easylogging++` and I get the same huge amount of warnings from the `easylogging++.h` even though the folder where it resides has been included with `SYSTEM` option.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for this. It has saved me from pages and pages of warnings.

Comment: I have used this strategy consistently for some time now but it breaks the compilation when used with the new gcc versions (at least > 6.0). The problem is that `-isystem` doesn't play well with the #include_next directive that is used for example that is now used in <cstdlib> (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218953/isystem-on-a-system-include-directory-causes-errors)

Comment: Same comment as for the accepted answer: this is bad practice for me.

Answer (score 67):

You can use pragmas. For example:

```
// save diagnostic state
#pragma GCC diagnostic push 

// turn off the specific warning. Can also use "-Wall"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-but-set-variable"

#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

// turn the warnings back on
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Only available with GCC >= 4.6

Comment: i'm loving the ability of push/pop pragmas. i remember something like for java available years ago and being frustrated/jealous for C/C++. i love that this is available in `gcc`

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith MS `cl` has had the ability for years too... At times `gcc` is a bit slow to adapted.

Comment: It seems you can only disable warnings one by one, i.e. `-Wall` does not work.  See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32049296/how-to-disable-all-warnings-using-pragma-directives-in-gcc)

Answer (score 35):

I found the trick. For library includes, instead of `-Idir` use `-isystem dir` in the makefile. GCC then treats boost etc. as system includes and ignores any warnings from them.

Comment: Note that if you use precompiled header you need to add the flag when you compile both the header and the code.

Answer (score 9):

`#pragma` are instructions to the compiler. you can set something before the #include and disable it after.

You can also do it at the [command line](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).

Another GCC page specifically on [disabling warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

I would go for the option of using #pragma's within the source code, and then providing a 
**sound** reason (as a comment) of why you are disabling the warnings. This would mean reasoning about the headers files.

GCC approaches this by [classifying](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas) the warning types. You can classify them to be warnings or to be ignored. The previously linked articles will show you which warnings are may be disabled.

Note: you can also massage the source code to prevent certain warnings by using [attributes](http://www.ohse.de/uwe/articles/gcc-attributes.html); however, this bind you quite closely to GCC.

Note2: GCC also uses the [pop/push interface](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Push_002fPop-Macro-Pragmas.html) as used in microsoft's compiler -- Microsoft disables warnings through this interface.  I suggest you investigate this further , as I do not know if it is even possible.

Comment: I considered pragmas but if I suppress a warning before including a header, how do I set it back to the *previous state* after #include? I want to see all warnings for the project code (helped me already a few times) but have control from command line.

Answer (score 6):

Putting the following

```
#pragma GCC system_header
```

will turn off GCC warnings for all following code in this file.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [precompiled headers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html). Warnings won't go away but at least the won't show up in your main compilation.

Comment: This might actually be a good idea. Third-party includes don't change every day.

Comment: Exactly. Although I haven't used them that much in Linux, they work pretty well on Visual Studio.

Comment: No, they will still show up in the compilation unless you use some other way to suppress them (such as `-isystem`, but remember to use it both in compiling the header and in the code)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to explicitly override a system header then you're restricted to pragmas.  You can verify which includes you're using via `make depend` output.

Also see [diagnostic push-pop for gcc >= 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555585/why-pragma-gcc-diagnostic-push-pop-warning-in-gcc-c)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is, in the makefile, to tell the compiler to ignore warnings for the specific folder:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/libs/%.c.o: CFLAGS += -w
```

Comment: This suppresses all warnings, not just those in the headers of external libraries, which very likely isn't desired.

Answer (score -10):

There must be reasons for those warnings. These will either be caused by errors in your code that uses the library,  or by errors in the library code itself. In the first case, fix your code. In the second case, either stop using the library or if it is FOSS code, fix it.

Comment: +1 for good advice :D but he is asking how to do something specific :D

Comment: Some warnings are impossible or very hard to fix, especially in 3rd-party code, *especially* in such metaprogramming-rich code as Boost's.

Comment: Worse the one that is bugging me is *"declaration of 'c' shadows a member of 'this' [-Werror=shadow]"* deep, deep in some boost header. That is certainly not a problem, but it and similar issues are spewing output and making it hard for me to find instances a real shadowing in our code-base.