# How to suppress boost::thread warnings with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, warnings, suppress-warnings

In my project, I recently decided to use boost::thread. My code compiles fine under Linux, but under Windows (either x86 or x64), I get the following warnings with gcc 4.5:

```
In file included from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp:14:0,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/detail/thread_group.hpp:9,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/thread.hpp:24,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread.hpp:13,
                 from include\systools/upnp_control_point.hpp:50,
                 from src\upnp_control_point.cpp:45:
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp: In member function 'T boost::shared_mutex::interlocked_
compare_exchange(T*, T, T) [with T = boost::shared_mutex::state_data]':
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:110:103:   instantiated from here
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:50:99: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will bre
ak strict-aliasing rules
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:50:99: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will bre
ak strict-aliasing rules
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:51:52: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will bre
ak strict-aliasing rules
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:51:52: error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will bre
ak strict-aliasing rules
In file included from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_format.hpp:18:0,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/find_format.hpp:23,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:22,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/date_time/date_facet.hpp:17,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_io.hpp:16,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp:31,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/date_time/posix_time/time_formatters.hpp:12,
                 from C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp:24,
                 from include\systools/upnp_device.hpp:51,
                 from include\systools/upnp_control_point.hpp:48,
                 from src\upnp_control_point.cpp:45:
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_format_store.hpp: At global scope:
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_format_store.hpp: In instantiation of 'bool boost::algori
thm::detail::check_find_result(InputT&, FindResultT&) [with InputT = std::basic_string<char>, FindResultT = boost::itera
tor_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> > >]':
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_format_all.hpp:259:17:   instantiated from 'void boost::a
lgorithm::detail::find_format_all_impl(InputT&, FinderT, FormatterT, FindResultT) [with InputT = std::basic_string<char>
, FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::first_finderF<const char*, boost::algorithm::is_equal>, FormatterT = boost::algori
thm::detail::const_formatF<boost::iterator_range<const char*> >, FindResultT = boost::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal
_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> > >]'
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/find_format.hpp:268:13:   instantiated from 'void boost::algorithm::f
ind_format_all(SequenceT&, FinderT, FormatterT) [with SequenceT = std::basic_string<char>, FinderT = boost::algorithm::d
etail::first_finderF<const char*, boost::algorithm::is_equal>, FormatterT = boost::algorithm::detail::const_formatF<boos
t::iterator_range<const char*> >]'
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp:654:13:   instantiated from 'void boost::algorithm::repla
ce_all(SequenceT&, const Range1T&, const Range2T&) [with SequenceT = std::basic_string<char>, Range1T = char [15], Range
2T = char [1]]'
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/units/detail/utility.hpp:50:51:   instantiated from here
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_44/boost/algorithm/string/detail/find_format_store.hpp:74:18: error: unused parameter 'Input'
scons: *** [src\upnp_control_point.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I just included `<boost/thread.hpp>` in my own `.cpp` file, nothing special.

Since I have no control over boost's code, is there a way to suppress those warnings temporarily ? Something like:

```
#super_killing_macro_that_disable_some_warnings
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#its_all_good_know_i_want_my_warnings_back
```

What can I do ?

Comment: you have `-Werror ` in command line, can you take it out?

Comment: @aaa carp: I'd like to keep it. I want my code to be 100% warning/error free. Of course, I have no control over other libraries source code so in this case, ignoring is fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suppress GCC warnings from library headers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just discovered the `-isystem` option that allow to include a directory as a system directory. No warnings are emited from files within thoses directories so it seems perfect for my task.

Also, this has the neat side effect to make `SCons` ignore those directories as well in the dependency tree. Since I'm not expecting those libraries to change often, it's fine.

Comment: All that does is stop the warnings, the code still violates strict aliasing rules and may be miscompiled.  Use `-fno-strict-aliasing` to tell the compiler not to perform optimisations that rely on the code following the rules.

Answer (score 1):

you may have some luck with diagnostic pragma:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know which flags to turn off. How can I know ?

Comment: @ereOn for starters, try `-Werror` and strict alias flags, I do not remember the exact option.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: The warning comes from `-Wstrict-aliasing` (which as Anycorn says, you find by reading the manual, of course).  If you compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` the compiler won't miscompile the code even if it violates strict aliasing rules, and the warning will also be suppressed.

Answer (score 1):

I am having almost the same warnings on Windows XP SP3 with MinGW installed from mingw-get-inst-20101030 with GCC 4.5.0 and boost 1.45.0 built as indicated here

http://fw-geekycoder.blogspot.com/2010/12/building-boost-using-mingw.html

I am using the BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB compiler flag and the -lboost_thread-mgw45-mt-1_45 linker flag. The only four warnings I am getting are as follows at the end of this post.

C:\workspace\boost_1_45_0/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:113:103:   instantiated from here
C:\workspace\boost_1_45_0/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:53:99: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
C:\workspace\boost_1_45_0/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:53:99: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
C:\workspace\boost_1_45_0/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:54:52: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
C:\workspace\boost_1_45_0/boost/thread/win32/shared_mutex.hpp:54:52: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

I haven't been able to get the resulting code not to crash yet, so I don't know if these warnings are important or not (by checking to see if threading changes my numerical results).