# Suppress -Wunknown-pragmas warning in GCC

Tags: gcc, warnings, pragma, suppress-warnings

I try to ignore warnings coming from some 3rd party header files like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreorder"

#include <some_3rd_party_header.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This approach seems to work in general, but not for the unknown pragma warnings (I still get them).

Why does it work for other warnings but not for this one? Can anyone confirm this behaviour?

I'm using g++ (version 4.7.1) with `-Wall` and `-std=c++0x` under Debian.

Comment: Hmm, gcc respects the suppression, g++ doesn't. Is `-Wno-unknown-pragmas` an option?

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess you mean as a command line parameter to the compiler? This would disable the warning also in my own code which I don't want.

Comment: Okay, understandable. Maybe you could try including these headers as system headers, as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1867065/1011995)?

Comment: That would be a nice solution indeed and it would have been my first choice from beginning. But I'm working with Eclipse (automatically generated make files) and Eclipse does not seem to offer a way to mark an include directory as system include directory. So it always uses `-I` and not `-isystem`.

Comment: Could be related to this bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431

Answer (score 31):

I've run into this annoyance, too. According to the GCC manpage `-Wall` turns on `-Wunknown-pragmas` for you, so just manually disable it using `-Wno-unknown-pragmas` after `-Wall`.

There is a GCC feature request to make this work using `#pragma GCC diagnostic`:

- [C++ preprocessor ignores #pragma GCC diagnostic](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431)