# Cannot temporarily disable unknown-pragmas warning in GCC

Tags: gcc, g++, pragma

I cannot make the method to temporarily disable warnings in GCC (see [How to disable GCC warnings for a few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code/26003732#26003732)) work, at least not for the "unknown-pragmas" warning.

Compiling this code ...

```
#pragma comment(user,"This should depend on the command line options")

#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma comment(user,"This should cause a warning")

#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma comment(user,"This should cause an error")

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#pragma comment(user,"This should be ignored")
```

... produces either no warning/error (except that the linker complais about a missing `main`), or when using `-Wall` or just `-Wunknown-pragmas` it produces one warning for each of the comment pragmas.

The behaviour that I would have expected is that each comment should have caused exactly what the comment says.

I think I can back my expectation with the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html):

> At the moment only warnings (normally controlled by ‘-W...’) can be controlled, and not all of them. Use `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to determine which diagnostics are controllable and which option controls them.

The warnings I get show as

```
warning: ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

and as the part in brackets tells us,

- this diagnostic **is** controllable
- and the option `-Wunknown-pragmas` controls it

Hence my code should work.

So what am I doing wrong?

---

version info:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress -Wunknown-pragmas warning in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842306/suppress-wunknown-pragmas-warning-in-gcc)

Answer (score 2):

This is a long-standing missing feature in the GCC C++ front end:

- [C++ preprocessor ignores #pragma GCC diagnostic](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431)

Warnings generated by preprocessing cannot be controlled using programs in `g++`.  Unlike the C front end, pragmas are processed only after the preprocessing phase in the C++ front end.