# Exception/exclusion for -Wpadded warning

Tags: c++, c, gcc, warnings, padding

I have *-Wpadded* warning option on (gcc/g++) and getting these warnings for non-padded C/C++ structures as expected.

Now, I want to exclude some of the structures from that warning without having to actually pad them.

To make things even more complicated - I have "-Wall". This makes the approach with `#pragma GCC diagnostics ignored -Wpadded` not usable (shame, would have been very neat).

Some sort of "pragma" directive in the code is what I would expect as a solution. Thanks in advance!

**Please note that there was a misspelling in my original question text! Refer to the accepted answer for the confirmation that the method with #pragma actually works!**

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the suggestion. Although it could have potentially worked, in my case I have "-Wall" on (not my decision), will add this to the question. The problem with -Wall is that with "#pragma GCC diagnostics push" I get "-Wunknown-pragmas".Will have to work this around somehow. But thanks to your suggestion I have found others struggling with very similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842306/suppress-wunknown-pragmas-warning-in-gcc.

Comment: You wrote `diagnostics` instead of `diagnostic`, so indeed that's an unknown pragma.

Comment: By the way, `-Wall` is good but add `-Wextra -pedantic` too for extra goodness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [GCC has pragmas for this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html):

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpadded"

// Doesn't warn
struct Foo { bool x; int y; };

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop


// Warns
struct Bar { bool x; int y; };
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f25dfcefca5f90e3))

Nothing about `-Wall` makes this complicated or in any way a problem; you just have to spell the pragma correctly.

Comment: Hm, it does actually work when you write it correctly. Thanks! :)

Comment: @OpalApps Magic :P