#pragma fenv_access (on) & #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
For the two pragmas
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

Does it matter I put them before of after #include headers?
Looks to me both are fine?
Why GCC does not support "#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON"?
Thanks.
I have code like this
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

#undef NDEBUG
#include <cassert>
#include <cfenv>
#include <cstdint>
#include <bit>
#include <stdfloat>


Compiled by GCC14.1.0
g++ -std=c++23 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-error=unknown-pragmas test.cpp
warning: ignoring ‘#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS’ [-Wunknown-pragmas]
8 | #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

Pragmas are inherently compiler-specific. Pragmas in one compiler are not guaranteed to work in another compiler.

@Someprogrammerdude C, unlike C++, actually requires the compiler to support some pragmas (including STDC FENV_ACCESS).

@yurikilochek   Yeah, but this question is tagged C++, not C, and the context is use of a C++ compiler (g++).     So this question amounts to "why doesn't this C++ compiler support a C-specific feature by default that is not required by the C++ standard?" for which the reason is mostly self-evident.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842306/suppress-wunknown-pragmas-warning-in-gcc
