# Why "pragma GCC diagnostic push" pop warning in GCC/C++?

Tags: c++, pragma

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push

it pop: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after â#pragma GCC diagnosticâ
```

Why? I use GCC in Linux.

I have one question, if I can't use pop/push, if the ignore **only** influence the compiled cpp, not influence other cpp? if some other include the cap, if influence it?

Comment: Those pragmas were introduced in gcc 4.6. Which version are you using?

Comment: [root@whf2wcc22 cfengine]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)

Comment: so if I don't use this pop/push in my cpp, what's the result? what it can influence？

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`#pragma GCC diagnostic push` and `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop` were [added in gcc 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html). You're using an older version.

These pragmas are typically used in conjunction with other [`#pragma GCC diagnostic` directives](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) to suppress, turn on, or turn into an error specific warnings for a small section of your code only. If they're ignored, the changes to warning levels will apply to the rest of the source file rather than just until the next `#pragma GCC diagnostic pop`. This may not be a problem, or it may be the end of the world; you'll need to understand your code to know for sure.

Either way, you should probably update your compiler. You wouldn't compile C99 with a C89 compiler; don't compile code containing pragmas for gcc 4.6 with gcc 4.4.

Comment: I have one question, if I can't use pop/push, if the ignore only influence the compiled cpp, not influence other cpp? if some other include my cap, if influence it?

Comment: If another source file includes your file directly, the changes in diagnostics in your file will also affect that source file.

Comment: I think you should be able to use `_Pragma()` and conditional controls based on GCC version (for example, `#if __GNUC__ > 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 6)` as a test).