# Suppressing the g++ warning "-Wliteral-suffix" for specific include headers

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I am working on a project, in which I use the new c++11 standard.
Because of that, few include-headers from a library now generate the warning `-Wliteral-suffix`, which I would supress for that includes.

I have found an easy solution for that using pragmas, but it doesn't work for me

[How to suppress GCC warnings from library headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers)

This is my current code:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wliteral-suffix"

#include <pylon/PylonBase.h>
#include <pylon/InstantCamera.h>
#include <pylon/TlFactory.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

All current Warnings generated by the library look like this:

```
/opt/pylon3/genicam/library/CPP/include/Base/GCException.h:272:105: warning: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wliteral-suffix]
```

I am using `gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)`

Comment: Run GCC with `-fdiagnostics-show-option` to see if that warning can be disabled; it could just be that GCC prevents you from disabling it.

Comment: Look like a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61653)

Answer (score 10):

I think you must use just the opposite: `-Wno-literal-suffix`. I'm also getting more problems with this version than with the old 4.7.2 (finest).

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting warnings from *system* headers, then you should include them as such:

```
# Makefile

CPPFLAGS += -isystem/path/to/python/prefix
```

References:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Answer (score 0):

The option to turn off the warning/error is compiler-specific. Assuming you have to support GCC and Clang, the options are

- GCC: `-Wno-literal-suffix`
- Clang: `-Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal` (or `-Wno-error=reserved-user-defined-literal`, if you want to keep seeing the warning message)
- MSVC: ???

Source: https://sourcecodeartisan.com/2021/03/06/invalid-suffix-on-literal.html