# Getting warning while compiling using cryptopp library

Tags: c++, c++11, crypto++

I have a encrypted file using AES algorithm in CBC mode. I have key from database.
I am trying to compile below code using cryptopp 5.6.2 library. It gets compiled without -Wall flag but when I enable that flag below warnings appears.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

#include "cryptopp/modes.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include "cryptopp/cryptlib.h"
#include "cryptopp/hex.h"
#include "cryptopp/filters.h"
#include "cryptopp/aes.h"
#include "cryptopp/ccm.h"
#include "cryptopp/files.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        byte no[16]  ;
        byte noiv[16];
        std::string out;
        std::string fileName("./encrypted.txt");
        CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption d;
        d.SetKeyWithIV(no, sizeof(no), noiv);
        CryptoPP::FileSource(fileName.c_str(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(d, new CryptoPP::FileSink("decrypted.txt"), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING));
    }
    catch (CryptoPP::Exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gets below errors on enabling -Wall flag

```
In file included from ./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/modes.h:12,
                 from poc.cpp:6:
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In constructor ‘CryptoPP::ConstByteArrayParameter::ConstByteArrayParameter(const T&, bool) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >]’:
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/filters.h:793:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:26: warning: unused variable ‘cryptopp_assert_26’
In file included from ./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/modes.h:12,
                 from poc.cpp:6:
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = std::ostream*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = const wchar_t*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = const char*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = std::istream*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = const int*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = unsigned char]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = const byte*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h: In member function ‘void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void*) const [with T = CryptoPP::RandomNumberGenerator*]’:
poc.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/misc.h: At global scope:
./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/misc.h:548: warning: ‘std::string CryptoPP::StringNarrow(const wchar_t*, bool)’ defined but not used
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `p` isn't used, nothing you can do about and most of all since it's a library issue you shouldn't care. Moreover, I'm pretty sure it has no impact

Comment: If you want to suppress those warnings for library headers check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers

Comment: @user3494614 - What is your compile command?

Answer (score 2):

> below code using cryptopp 5.6.2 library...

5.6.2 is kind of old. We are getting ready to release Crypto++ 5.6.5.

---

> It gets compiled without -Wall flag but when I enable that flag below warnings appears.
>
> ```
> ./cryptopp_5.6.2/include/cryptopp/algparam.h:322: warning: unused variable ‘p’
> ```

The warning was cleared about 18 months ago. It was first seen in a release at Crypto++ 5.6.3. Also see [Commit 5f25c736: Add CRYPTOPP_UNUSED to help supress unused variable warnings](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/5f25c7363534656ce6e1ecac63ca694e6d4ba7d6).

---

> Gets below errors on enabling -Wall flag ...

Crypto++ is now clean at `-Wall -Wextra` under GCC and compatibles. Its also clean under MSC with `/W4`. Finally, its clean under Solaris' SunCC.

If interested, here is the release process and security gates we are required to pass through for a release (from [Release Process | Analysis Tools](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Release_process#Analysis_Tools)):

- Compiler Warnings
- Clang and GCC Sanitizers
- Valgrind
- Enterprise Analysis
- Coverity

Right now, Coverity is holding-up 5.6.5. We recently expanded Coverity coverage to [Linux, Unix, OS X, and Windows](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Coverity_Scan) (previously it was Linux only). Coverity is producing findings and we are working through them.