# Suppressing a deprecated warning for a single line

Tags: c++, gcc

In a project, I use (a somewhat old version of) VTK, which produces a deprecated warning on GCC:

```
In file included from <path STL>/backward/strstream:51:0,
             from <path VTK>/vtkIOStream.h:112,
             from <path VTK>/vtkSystemIncludes.h:40,
             from <path VTK>/vtkIndent.h:24,
             from <path VTK>/vtkObjectBase.h:43,
             from <path VTK>/vtkSmartPointerBase.h:26,
             from <path VTK>/vtkSmartPointer.h:23,
             from <some file in my project>
<path STL>/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]
```

I want to suppress that warning. What I tried so far was trying to use pragma directives along the culprit line:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wno-deprecated"

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

as recommended in an answer to [How to suppress several warnings but not all of them coming from libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41385771/how-to-suppress-several-warnings-but-not-all-of-them-coming-from-libraries)

This however does not work because the command does not recognize my option:

```
warning: unknown option after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’ kind [-Wpragmas]
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wno-deprecated"
```

I wanted to be specific here with what type of warning I disable. An answer that gives me a less specific option would also be welcome, though. I tried with it "-Wall", but that doesn't work either (recognized but does not suppress).

Compiling the whole project with -Wno-deprecated suppresses the warning, and this is my fallback option, but not one I like to go with.

Emphasis of mine is that it works under Linux with GCC. I have no administration rights, can't change the VTK version here or the version of GCC (4.8.5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As state in comment:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

as `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` is to **ignore** specified warning flag, not substitute it.

As alternative you can use the flag reported in error message: `[-Wcpp]`:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcpp"

#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Ah of course, I did a double negation. Now I feel somewhat stupid :). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but right now I'm using exactly your code, that is the first block with ignoring -Wdeprecated, but it still produces the warning, and it does so exactly where I use those. And as I compile with -Wunknown-pragmas, I am also sure that it recognizes it. Do you happen to know other reasons why it not might work?

Comment: Can you try second snippet ? From [gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) *"Note that not all diagnostics are modifiable. Use -fdiagnostics-show-option to determine which diagnostics are controllable and which option controls them."*

Comment: Doesn't work either. I also tried to remove -W and -Wall. The warning says " warning: #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated. [-Wcpp]" so I assume it is caused by -Wcpp, but again, the second snippet doesn't work either for some reason.

Comment: I did another test to be sure, in which I used `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` four times to remove -Wdeprecated, -Wcpp, -Wall and -W just to be sure, followed by a simple `#warning test`. It is triggered. My Makefile currently sets `CXXFLAGS      = -std=c++11 -fdiagnostics-show-option -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT $(DEFINES)` (with DEFINES having only flags relevant to Qt and OpenGL)

Comment: The second suggestion will not work for g++: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80650