# How to suppress deprecation warning for a single function in C?

Tags: clang, deprecation-warning

I would like to suppress deprecation warnings for a single function in C. I.e., I want that the use of a function:

```c
void deprecated_func(void)
```

stop to produce a deprecation warning, while I would like that all other deprecated functions still continue to produce deprecation warning (i.e., I still want a warning if using `void another_deprecated_func(void)`).

I can find some solutions for ignoring deprecation warnings on all functions (see for example [Suppressing a deprecated warning for a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54573282/suppressing-a-deprecated-warning-for-a-single-line) ), but not for a single function. Any idea if this is doable and how in c-lang? (I am using GCC, so a GCC-solution would be enough, but if you have something general it would be great :) ).

Comment: deprecation....

Comment: Hehe, thanks for the fixes, I am not a native speaker... :)