# Limit C++ warning in visual studio code to a subdirectory

Tags: visual-studio-code, warnings, bazel

I am a developer of a C++ application within an organization. We are using `bazel` as a compilation system while the IDE is Visual Studio Code.

I am developing a library by myself that is in a separate directory within the bigger project. While compiling there are lots of warnings and Visual Studio Code also displays them.

How could I limit the warnings to the subdirectory that I'm working in, especially in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: VSCode is not a compiler. The options to limit the scope of warnings depends on the compiler used. If you are using gcc as your compiler this may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547296/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-third-party-source-code-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547296/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-third-party-source-code-in-eclipse)

Comment: You might have different settings by project...