# suppress warnings from system headers did not work

Tags: header, g++, suppress-warnings

I try to compile gmock headers and get tons of warnings like:

> /opt/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gtest/gtest.h:10298:40: warning: 'testing::internal::ParamIteratorInterface* testing::internal::ValuesInIteratorRangeGenerator::Iterator::Clone() const [with T = bool]' can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]

I already include the gmock headers with `-isystem` as described here:
[How to suppress GCC warnings from library headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers)

I compile with:

> g++ -Wsuggest-override -I ../ -I ../../generic/ -isystem /opt/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gmock/ -isystem /opt/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src -g -Wall -pedantic -pthread -std=c++14 -O2   /opt/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0/fused-src/gmock-gtest-all.cc -c -o build-ut-std-xsysg-nomemdbg-o2-dynamic-noncov//opt/foreign_components/gmock-1.7.0    /fused-src/gmock-gtest-all.o

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You could remove -Wsuggest-override option

Comment: @lostbard: Yeah ;) OK, you are right. But I want to have all my sources compiled with -Wsuggest-override and only in the included system headers I did not want to see the warnings.

Comment: How about using the #progma options mentioned from your link?

Comment: @lostbard: the files are not under my control. If I could change them with pragma, I can also add the missing override itself. So problem here is that I have to compile the '*.cc' files from the gmock itself.

Comment: without code changes to the code, the only method I believe is remove the warning flag