# YouCompleteMe conf file for inspecting libraries header files without reporting the library errors

Tags: c++, vim, vim-plugin, youcompleteme

I work with external C++ libraries (OpenFst). I add them into the include path so I can get IntelliSense, GoToDefinition/GoToDeclaration, etc.

Some of these **external libraries include code smells and YCM diagnostic is reporting a lot of warnings.**
I want to get warnings for the code I develop, but I want to suppress the warnings from the OpenFST library (and other libraries I use as a dependency).

**Is there a way to keep the Intellisense and suppress Diagnostics for a specific library?**

Link to my [.ycm_extra_conf.py with OpenFst added to the include path](https://github.com/oplatek/dotfiles-vim/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py#L32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized this functionality needs to be supported by compilers.

The solution is to use `'-isystemMY_EXTERNAL_LIBRARY'` instead of `'-IMYEXTERNAL_LIBRARY'` in my `.ycm_extra_conf.py`

It is basically [already answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867065/how-to-suppress-gcc-warnings-from-library-headers)