# How to turn off -Werror for a specific header file

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, g++, warnings

My project uses `-Werror` to turn GCC 11.3.0 g++ warnings to errors and stop the build.  But a 3rd party header file we need to include causes a bunch of warnings to be issued by the compiler.

I was hoping there is a way to turn off `-Werror` for that 1 include file.  Maybe a `#pragma` I can issue just before and just after that header file is invoked?

However, it does not seem to be the case.  Best I can find is to disable individual warnings with `#pragma GCC diagnostic ...`, which would make me list all of the warnings that this header file causes.

Is that really the case or did I miss something obvious?

---

**Edit:**

Turns out some warnings/errors can be disabled, but others cannot.  For example, this works to remove the signed/unsigned warnings:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare"
#include <problematic_include.hpp>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

But this does not work:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunknown-pragmas"
#include <problematic_include.hpp>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

...to remove the error about `error: ignoring ‘#pragma _CVUI_COMPILE_MESSAGE ’ [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867065/5754656 (Use `include_directories(SYSTEM "/path/to/cvui")` in CMake or otherwise `-isystem` instead of `-I`)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to not name the 3rd party library that caused this, but it turns out in this case the library itself provides a solution to the problem.

The library is [CVUI](https://github.com/Dovyski/cvui#cvui), which provides some simple GUI functionality based on OpenCV.  It is a header-only library.  Turns out it has a macro called `CVUI_DISABLE_COMPILATION_NOTICES` which prevents the problematic `#pragma` line that was causing g++ to stop compiling.

In the end, as ugly as this is, here is the solution I chose:

```
#define CVUI_IMPLEMENTATION
#define CVUI_DISABLE_COMPILATION_NOTICES
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare"
#include "cvui.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This way the `cvui.h` file can be successfully included from within a project that uses `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

Comment: you can create a `cvui_wnoerror.h` that contains this ugly boilerplate and in your project you can include this header instead of doing all of this everywhere you include `cvui.h`